# Best practices for updates

Tags: centos7, yum, high-availability, update

We have a lot of Linux servers (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 running vmware) and most of the services are in containers docker. We want to implement a policy of updating our systems with minimal disruption of services.

What would be the best approach to update the system (patches, security patches and kernel) either to have no downtime or to have the shortest service downtime?
Thank you